# How to find only the eigen values without finding eigen vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a large matrix for which I want to find only the eigen values. I know I can use charpoly(A) and find roots, but even that is very slow (takes about a minute). Is there a fast way to find only the eigen values for the matrix.

Furthermore, my matrix happens to be a symmetric PSD covariance matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by large? Have you simply tried `eig`?

Comment: You can try `[~,D] = eig(A)`

Comment: AFAIK, you can not store them (as Dan suggests) but to compute them you need to compute the eigenvectors. In the end, it is a projection into a new coordinate system.

Comment: I have tried eig, Large is > 24K or something usually. I want to save time and all solutions should approach the question in that way as I already have specified. And AFAIK, we don't need to find eigenvectors to find eigenvalues at least theoretically.

Comment: `e = eig(A)`. @AnderBiguri, the poster wants only the eigen*values*, and that's possible. Dan's solution is also correct, but gives the eigenvectors as a diagonal matrix instead of a vector.

Comment: @A.Donda oh yeah. But I think that `eig` does calculate everything (because is needed) to output the eigenvalues. If the OP wants to speed up by not calculating eigenvectors that may not be the answer. Would need to test though.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I'm not sure about the implementation details of `eig` either, but it is possible in principle to compute eigenvalues without eigenvectors. The eigenvalues are simply the roots of the characteristic polynomial.